# Android Events: When implementing interfaces is it better to use the outer class or anonymous classes

Tags: android, events, class, interface

This is an example of using outer class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        findViewById(R.id.myid).setOnClickListener(this));
    }
    public void onClick(View v){...}
}
```

This is an example of anonymous classes

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        findViewById(R.id.myid).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){...}
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance and efficiency are slightly a  more important consideration in Android. Something considered to be half baked optimization effort, sometimes makes sense in android.(like we should not use enum but java int enum pattern). So to the answer to your question is.

If you have to register multiple onClick listeners, Implement interface and use switch case within it.

If you have to register only one on click listener, use anonymous class. (Android developers prefers anonymous class, whenever possible. Limiting the scope ;))